# VSCode uses wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rbenv

I'm having an issue with VSCode on Ubuntu. I have the ruby extension and the ruby-rubocop extensions installed but when I run the rubocop extension on save, I get 2 errors

- rbenv: version '2.5.1' is not installed (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
- command /home/{username}/.rbenv/shims/rubocop returns empty output! please check configuration.

My project is using ruby version 2.7.6 installed via rbenv. 2.5.1 is an old version of ruby I had installed which I since removed. I don't understand why VSCode is trying to use version 2.5.1. When I run rubocop via a bash shell, it runs as expected. `rbenv local` and `rbenv global` are all set to `2.7.6` and my project as a `.ruby-version` file with 2.7.6 set.

When I run `echo $RBENV_VERSION` in a bash shell, I get nothing returned, but if I run this in a terminal shell within VSCode, it returns 2.5.1.

How do I get VSCode to use the correct rbenv version?

Solution:

I found that the issue was that I had for some reason defined the RBENV version in my .bash_profile file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem as well. Further symptoms: `rbenv shell` asked me to perform rbenv init. This happend both inside and ouside VS Code. I was sure I'd done that in the past, but the init line no longer was in my shell init script.

The solution was to run `rbenv init` and follow the instructions (i.e. adding the suggested line to `.bashrc`, or the appropriate file for your shell).

This sets `$RBENV_VERSION` to the correct version and thus fixes the problem. I am not aware of why thie problem appears only in VS Code but not in the regular terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You helped me find the issue. For some reason, I had "RBENV_VERSION =2.5.3" in my .bash_profile file. Very embarassing!