Ruby LSP VS Code extension is not starting and uses wrong ruby version
I have installed the extension.
I have updated the settings accordingly
{
    "ruby.useLanguageServer": true,
    "ruby.intellisense": "rubyLocate",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Spinel"
}

When I do cmd + click is not navigating to the code definition.
When I am trying to start the server I am getting the following
Command Ruby LSP Start resulted in an error
The ruy LSP requires Ruby 3.0 or newer to run. This project is using 2.6.10

But my ruby version is actually newer
ruby -v
ruby 3.1.3p185 (2022-11-24 revision 1a6b16756e) [arm64-darwin22]


I have also updated the rubyLsp.rubyPath but still nothing
"rubyLsp.rubyPath": "/Users/username/.rbenv/shims/ruby"

Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73897013/vscode-uses-wrong-ruby-version? There is also this: https://github.com/Shopify/vscode-ruby-lsp/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#check-the-vs-code-output-tab, showing you can set your version manager.

Which OS? It might be useful to add that to your tags. I suspect you're on MacOS based on the message "This project is using 2.6.10" since that's the built-in version found at /usr/bin. In addition to the links proved by @engineersmnky, you should check whether rbenv is finding a .ruby-version file in the project directory.
